# Dynamic CSS for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

It looks like the .NET community in general has not picked up on CSS compilers. In searching Google I've not found anything even remotely relevant.

Has anyone that is using ASP.NET MVC figured out a scheme to more intelligently generate their CSS? I'd love to be able to run my CSS through Razor for example, or for SASS to get ported over or what have you. Maybe I have a new side project on my hands :)

Comment: don't know if it's what you're looking for, but I've started using [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com) and love it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> I'd love to be able to run my CSS through Razor

What stops you?

```
public class CssViewResult : PartialViewResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return new CssViewResult();
    }
}
```

and in `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    var color = "White";
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 18 || DateTime.Now.Hour < 8)
    {
        color = "Black";
    }
}
.foo {
    color: @color;
}
```

Now all that's left is to include it:

```
<link href="@Url.Action("index")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You can also make the template strongly typed to a view model, write loops, ifs, inclusions, ...

Comment: Nice, this is along the lines of something I was thinking of. I assume this could be combined with Output caching and for the most part the dynamic CSS wont cost anymore than a static file? My CSS isn't dynamic in the sense it changes often, but that I'd prefer to write my CSS in a more intelligent manner, so I really could cache it indefinitely.

Comment: @Matt Greer, CSS files are already cached by the browser, but here we are talking about dynamic CSS aren't we? That's what you wanted in the first place. So if you want them to be dynamic make sure that you use the proper output caching on your controller action (maybe even disable cache, or set expiration policies) or the controller action might be hit only once per client and cached by the browser. So be careful with this stuff. Make sure to perform extensive testing depending on your scenario and requirements.

Comment: I guess "dynamic" was not the correct term. I'm more looking for "compiled" css, where I can use variables, loops, nesting etc so that I can construct my css more efficiently at development time. I doubt my css will ever change dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Is there a way to have syntax highlighting in Visual Studio for this? (CSS in cshtml)

Comment: Darin, Nice & simple solution! My only complaint is that, since the css is now in a cshtml, I lose all the color-coding that VS and CodeRush provides (black & white, argh!). Is there any way to adapt your solution to return the original .css file?

Comment: Note, if you use MasterPages and Areas, and this is in your highest-level MasterPage, the Css Controller won't be called once you navigate into the area. To fix this, simply add a parameter specifying the area as emtpystring:  <link href="@Url.Action("GetCss", "Css", new { area = "" })" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - How do you pass in the VM when you make it strongly typed?

Comment: @chobo2, you could add a constructor to your `CssViewResult` class that will take the model as parameter and simply assign the ViewData property in it: `this.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);`;

Comment: Simple, elegant, practical solution and works great. A huge thanks.

Comment: where should i include the link?

Answer (score 6):

A slight modification of @darin-dimitrov's answer. This adds the ability to pass in a model to the CssView:

```
public class CssViewResult : PartialViewResult
{
    public CssViewResult()
    {

    }

    public CssViewResult(object model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            ViewData.Model = model;
        }
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

and then you just consume it with:

```
return new CssViewResult(model);
```

Answer (score 3):

Phil Haack has made a blog post about LessCSS and .net:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/02/t4-template-for-less-css.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, I am fairly new to ASP.NET.

Working with ASP.NET *Core*, I am trying to use @Darin Dimitrov's answer to allow me to set custom styles using data from an external API. To the OP's question, I know you said "Dynamic" but it seems as though you really want "Compiled". I am looking for "Dynamic".

It appears the technique of returning a partial view with response type `text/css` works pretty well for this solution. However, the syntax used here does not work for me in ASP.NET Core 3.1. Here is the solution I used:

Instead of `HomeController` I am using `ThemeController` as it is relevant to me.

In `ThemeController.cs`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var colors = await _apiService.GetThemeColors();
        Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        return PartialView(colors);
    }
```

In the view `~/Views/Theme/Index.cshtml`

```
@model ThemeColors
@{
    var color = Model.primaryColor;
}
.btn-primary {
    background-color: @color;
}
```

And then in my `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<link href="@Url.Action("Index", "Theme")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I hope this helps someone, if anyone who is more knowledgeable around this topic can point to more relevant resources that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4, Adding `ContentType="text/css"` to the page directive works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Posting below solution hoping that might help someone, not sure if this is best way to implement.

I had to populate input elements dynamically inside one of the tables column field, so i had to set `css` `position` field dynamically while looping through data.

Here is the code snippet,

```
            <td>
                <label>Extract Values</label>
                @{ int topPostn = 20; string topPs;}
               
                <div style="position:relative">
                    @foreach (var extracts in ViewData["excode"] as List<ExtractCode>)
                    {
                        topPostn += 25;
                        topPs = (topPostn).ToString() + "px";
                        <span style="position: absolute; top: @topPs" >
                            <input class="ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="someid" value="@extracts.value" name="xyz" aria-label="Toggle Row Selection">@extracts.displayName
                        </span>
                    }
                    @{ topPostn = 20; topPs = "";}
                </div>
            <td>
```