# How to set a model with a class that inherits partialviewresult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've based a dynamic css solution as mentioned here:

[Dynamic CSS for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492748/dynamic-css-for-asp-net-mvc)

I notice the inherited PartialViewResult only has a getter for the Model, is there another way I can implement this functionality where HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/css"  and I can send in a model like you can with a partialview?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply adapt the custom action result so that it takes a model:

```
public class CssViewResult : PartialViewResult
{
    public CssViewResult(object model)
    {
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Css()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...
    return new CssViewResult(model);
 }
```

and in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
    var color = "White";
    if (Model.Hour > 18 || Model.Hour < 8)
    {
        color = "Black";
    }
}
.foo {
    color: @color;
}
```