# Css view Model with Razor in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is my view as a `.css` file,

```
@model StyleProfile

body {

color: @Model.color;
}
```

and I included this to my layout,

```
<link href="@Url.Action("CssDynamic")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I have this in my controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private OnepageCMSEntities db = new OnepageCMSEntities();
    public ActionResult CssDynamic()
    {
        var model = db.StyleProfiles.FirstOrDefault();
        return new CssViewResult();
    }
}

public class CssViewResult : PartialViewResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }        
}
```

It works fine. But I need to send a model to the view and the problem appears when I send a model object in the `ActionMethod` "CssDynamic"

```
 return new CssViewResult(model);
```

The error says

```
"this does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments.
```

How can I modify `CssViewResult` class to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you sending a model to a view and trying to send it as a CSS file? Can you give some background on what you are trying to achieve? There may be a better way.

Comment: You are missing a contructor in your `CssViewResult` Class. Explain what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @HarveySpecter I would imagine OP is wanting to use the default constructor from `PartialViewResult`

Comment: Possibly, but clearly wont work since he needs a contructor of `CssViewResult`.

Comment: i want to use this  to dynamicaly change my css file . i need to send this model object to ~/home/CssDynamic (Strongly type view ,that is my css file).

Comment: @user2717912 You have a strongly typed view as your CSS file? I am lost. So you want to dynamically change your CSS file, based on model properties? What in the CSS are you trying to manipulate?

Comment: i edited my question and added the view code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the parameterized constructor for CssViewResult class. Add the following before ExecuteResult method in CssViewResult class.

```
    public CssViewResult(object model)
    {
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
    }
```

Also refer this stackoverflow post for the same.

[How to set a model with a class that inherits partialviewresult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198546/how-to-set-a-model-with-a-class-that-inherits-partialviewresult)

Answer (score 1):

You should to create the constructor with appropriate argument like this:

```
    public class CssViewResult : PartialViewResult
    {
        private readonly object model;

        public CssViewResult(object model)
        {
            this.model = model;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            // Do something with this.model
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
            base.ExecuteResult(context);
        }
    }
```