# CSS Partial View in Razor MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've been reseraching dynamic CSS and the best solution I can find seems to be [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919754/css-view-model-with-razor-in-asp-net-mvc), It's all looking good so far even though I made some changes but the one thing I can seem to figure out is what the View should be named and where I should place it.

I'm assuming that becasue it's a partial view it should be placed in Shared, but wanted to check that assumption. The controller the partial view code is located in is a Base Controller that all the other contollers then inherit (not sure if that makes a difference).

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
            public ActionResult CssDynamic()
            {
                Layout page = new Layout();
                var dummyCorpId = 80;

                page.Css = GetCss(dummyCorpId);

                var model = page;
                return new CssViewResult(model);
            }

     }

    public class CssViewResult : PartialViewResult
    {
            private readonly object model;

            public CssViewResult(object model)
            {
                this.model = model;
            }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
                base.ExecuteResult(context);
            }
        }
```

I've then added the action to the _Layout page, just not sure which View name to use or where to place it. Any help appriciated :)

Comment: Do you even actually need that in your inheritance hierarchy? You can just make 1 controller for your dynamic css and use it everywhere you need.

Comment: Possibly not to be honet but I reckon it might make it easier further down the line when I add the suth stuff whoch needs to be in a base controller as the css will be dependant upon user

Comment: In this case you can inherit your dynamic css controller from your base controller. Inheritance here might make sense if you need to override your dynamic css in different controllers. Otherwise I would recommend putting css code in a separate controller.

Comment: I'll definitely think bout it - I think what you're saying there makes sense - however in the man time whilst I get this tested to make sure it's going to run do you know what I would name the view and where I would put it for this example?

Comment: In your case by conventions you should name it `CssDynamic.cshtml` and put it to `Views/Shared` folder. Another option is to put a copy of view with same name to each controller, that inherits your `BaseController`, which I highly do not recommend. Let me know if that does not work for you.