# .NET - Dynamically Loading App Configurations Based on URL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a business application in .NET using MVC4. The application will be used by multiple corporate customers, each possessing their own branding elements (including a stylesheet and logo image). The UI calls web services for a back-end platform in order to populate various regions of the application; customer-specific parameters must be provided when calling these web services.

My goal is to deploy a single instance of the application while making the application dynamically load the appropriate brand scheme and web service parameters based on a portion of the URL itself. The application will be a public-facing consumer application (hosted by my organization on behalf of the corporate customer), so the URL must be easy to remember (and thereby not rely on querystring parameters for access), such as https://mysite.com/companyname.

The intent is to provide a product with a single code base and feature set (making the product easier to support than having multiple distinct deployments for each corporate customer) while supporting a limited degree of branding. I'm OK with a small bit of manual operational setup (such as creating a new app.config, web.config, or virtual directory for each customer).

**Can anyone recommend a suggested approach or best practices for implementing this type of application? Note that if the URL structure must be parsed, I'll need to ensure that the structure can be replicated properly in development, QA, and staging environments.**

My current approach requires distinct deployments of the application to different customer-specific environments, with the custom branding and web service parameters referenced as "appsettings" keys in the web.config file, which is different for each customer. This is OK for a small number of deployments, but will get unwieldy as feature upgrades / bug fix pushes become necessary for tens or hundreds of customer sites. Thank you!

Comment: Just wondered if you have considered scaling options for tens (or hundreds) of companies accessing a single web site?

Comment: Hi oleksii - yes, the site is hosted on a load balanced platform that's handling roughly 1.2 million web service-based requests per day and about 2 billion batch transactions (on the database) per quarter. A single corporate customer using this app will probably see 1000 to 5000 requests on a heavy day, with down days being around 10 requests. If I could get 25, 50, or 100 deployments on a single load balanced web/app server platform before having to do a second deployment of the code, I'd be very happy (I'm mainly trying to solve for operational deployment / version overhead). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a dynamic stylesheet for most of it.  There is an ok example here [Dynamic CSS for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492748/dynamic-css-for-asp-net-mvc) and a full source example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/171695/Dynamic-CSS-using-Razor-Engine

The rest of it is details.  You'll want to parse the company identifier out of the url (or cookie - useful for testing it in dev/qa).  You'll want to pull the customer specific values out of storage, database or config file whatever is appropriate for you.  One unrelated thing to think about. https://mysite.com/companyname.  What if the company changes their name?  You might want a user friendly looking but secretly technical url like https://mysite.com/companyname/590.  You can show the user friendly name, but ignore it in your code and just use the company id.  Then if the company changes names, no biggie - https://mysite.com/somethingElse/590.

Comment: This is very helpful! I'll try this out and follow-up with how it turns out. Would you suggest changing the MVC route structure itself to accommodate the company name / company ID? Thanks!

Comment: Look at how stackoverflow does it :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505451/net-dynamically-loading-app-configurations-based-on-url.  11505451 looks like an id for the questions area, which pulls up the customer friendly net-dynamically-loading-app-configurations-based-on-url.  It's up to you which one you put first, the id first is probably easier.  And it's really probably more user friendly, but a small business may not get it and want their name first

Comment: Perfect! I ended up adding "companyid" and "companyname" parameters to my MVC route, so now I have https://mysite.com/companyname/companyid. If the company ID isn't provided, I look it up based on the name and then all other operations use the ID. I ended up creating a folder structure for each client, so the site has a Clients/CompanyID/ folder. That folder contains style information and image resources specific to the client, along with a config file for the client-specific web service parameters. Works like a charm, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to create a directory structure having one folder for each customer. Then in every folder has its own customer specific files e.g css, templates, brandings etc.
You can also have a shared/common folder that gets applied at the start of your application which is shared among all the customers.

The only thing then you need to extract from your URL is the name of the client (if possible somehow). This will decide which folder and its contents to load and apply.