# Url.Content doesn't work in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have my images stored in `Content/Images` folder. Now I want to use one of them as a background in `CSS`. I found something in the Internet that I should use `Url.Content("~/Content/Images")` to reference my files.

I wrote something like this:

```
#main_background {
    background-image: url('@Url.Content("~Content/Images/background_car.png")');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And in my bundles' config file:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/layout_css").Include("~/Content/layout.css"));
```

When I preview `HTML` code in `Chrome's view:source` I see that nothing was parsed at all. `CSS` looks the same as above.

Later I tried to change it for:

```
#main_background {
    background-image: url('Images/background_car.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And in the bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/layout_css").Include("~/Content/layout.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

It started working, but I saw in some articles that I should use the 1st method. Why do I have problems with it? Isn't `Razor` engine obliged to parse `Url.Content` references?

Comment: Only views are parsed, not CSS files or anything else.

Comment: Honestly I'd just use a good relative path and use a base tag in my HTML, that would make you a lot less dependent on asp.net and will work everywhere anyway.

Comment: Oh, so I can't use it in `CSS`:S I found some article with a mistake:/ The guy who was talking about `Url.Content`, used it within `CSS` file

Comment: Well, at least not by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492748/dynamic-css-for-asp-net-mvc But in your CSS you should just use relative paths like @BenjaminGruenbaum says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use any razor syntax in css, thus it will never work.