# ASP.Net MVC: How to use razor variable in CSS file

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

as per my scenario i need to store this path **/img/product.png** of image in razor variable and later i want to use that razor variable in CSS file. below css code is in css file

```
.test{
    background: url('/img/product.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

so i use code like this way below but no luck still

```
.test{
    background: url('@Model.LogoUrl') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

i see this post **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/171695/Dynamic-CSS-using-Razor-Engine**  but i do not want to solve my issue as per the post. so let me know how to sort this issue. thanks

Comment: Better to use internal style sheet in view itself.

Comment: @ssilas777 sorry do not understand what u try to say......can u plzz come wit some example to describe what u said. thanks

Comment: is this code on your .cshtml file or .css file?

Comment: it is possible, and it's already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492748/dynamic-css-for-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, MVC does not support writing server side codes in external CSS file and external Javascript files.

For your case to work, you can add an internal stylesheet in your view file itself, it will work.

Eg:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Title";
}
<style>
    .test {
        background: url('@Model.LogoUrl') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    }  
</style>
```

Comment: It is similar to same question

Comment: No he is trying to put in external css file, I want him to put in view itself.

Comment: background: url('@url.content(Model.LogoUrl)'); may help :)

Comment: how to return view which will have only css with razor variable ? looking for a similar article on this subject. please discuss how to achieve it. thanks

Comment: I didn't get your question clearly.. Can you post it as a seperate question.. I'll surely try to help

Comment: -1 the answer is plain wrong. It IS POSSIBLE, of course. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492748/dynamic-css-for-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @MladenB. I answered by default MVC doesn't support writing razor code in external css file.In his case he only had to use this for a particular case and my solution worked for him. Also the answer you posted is just the same answer he pointed in his question which he doesn't want to make use of.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot refer or write Razor code in a CSS file. CSS files are processed by the browser where as the Razor code is executed by the server and then rendered by the browser

For your problem, you will need to write an inline style

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492748/dynamic-css-for-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in HTML part like this:

For example:

```
<div class="test" style="background: url(..@Model.LogoUrl) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">
...
</div>
```