# Razor loop in CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an .cshtml page. The page has an `<style>` tag with some css rules. I want to use foreach loop in this tag. Such as

```
@model Foo[]

<style>
    @foreach(var foo in Model)
    {
        .someClass-@foo.ClasName {
            background: @foo.Background;
        }
    }
</style>
```

But this code doesn't work. I've got an `System.Web.HttpException here`. 
I can modify this code by adding `@:` before each css-line:

```
<style>
    @foreach(var foo in Model)
    {
        @:.someClass-@foo.ClasName {
            @:background: @foo.Background;
        @:}
    }
</style>
```

It work. But `<style>` has a lot of lines and it looks bad if I add `@:` before each line. Is there another and simpler way to do this?

Comment: `I've got an System.Web.HttpException here` Where is `here`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC: How to use razor variable in CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634679/asp-net-mvc-how-to-use-razor-variable-in-css-file)

Comment: @Izzy thank you but your advice can not help me because my problem in foreach loop

Comment: @mjwills in line `.someClass-@foo.ClasName {` and all css-lines without prefix `@:`

Comment: You can use the `<text>` tags instead for multiple lines (refer [ASP.NET MVC 3: Razor’s @: and <text> syntax](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try to use the

```
@Html.Raw()
```

Razor Funktion to render your plain code to the view.